# Declaring variables for intermediate calculations and performance

Tags: c#, performance-testing, variable-declaration

Sorry this is such a dumb question, but I just have to ask this. I have a program that runs billions of calculations and I'm trying to get it to run faster. In my program, I declare a lot of variables for intermediate calculations. For example, in pseudo code:

```
public bool FunctionThatGetsCalledInMain(manyparameters)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        int x = bigFunctionThatReturnsAnInt(i,manyparameters)
        double y = bigFunctionThatReturnsADouble(i,manyparameters)
        string z = bigFunctionThatReturnsAString(i,manyparameters)

        bool b = someFunctionOfXYZ(x,y,z)
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if I can improve performance by doing something like:

```
public bool FunctionThatGetsCalledInMain(manyparameters)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        bool b = someFunctionOfXYZ(bigFunctionThatReturnsAnInt(i,manyparameters),bigFunctionThatReturnsADouble(i,manyparameters),bigFunctionThatReturnsAString(i,manyparameters))
    }
}
```

I know it looks horrendous, and my intuition tells me it doesn't really matter, but I just wanted to see if others agree.

Comment: Is this java, c#, or c++? I'm pretty sure it can't be all three.

Comment: Run a profiler to see the real bottleneck.

Comment: Actually none of these, it's in F#, but I thought this kind of issue is the same across all languages. I'll edit the tags.

Comment: it is the same in all languages that there is no "one strategy fits all" solution. Profile and find the hotspots.

Comment: It's doing the same work to create the variable, whether you name it or not.

Comment: most compilers now are probably smart enough to do this already, but you could move the declarations outside the loop.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the fact that the functions rely in i, so I can't move it outside the loop. I edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't try to "optimize" the performance this way. Modern compilers will produce the identical code from both versions, so there will be no any difference in terms of performance, but your code will be unreadable.

In general first case is much more readable, and that's why preferred. It clearly names temporary variable, that helps to understand code better. Moreover, it's much easier to debug.

Comment: And don't forget when you're verifying this, to compile the program in Release mode and run without the debugger attached.  Debugger attachment and Debug mode will prevent any optimizations.